# Android automatic keyboard language depending on the person you are writing to

Tags: android, keyboard, contacts, autocorrect

I often find myself writing to different people in different languages. Every time I have to switch to the correct language to avoid false auto-correction.

**The language only depends on the person I am talking to**, that is I will always talk in italian to `a`, `b` and `c`; in english to `l` and `m`; in french with `x`.

Is there a keyboard that keeps track of that, or a way to have it automatically configured when switching contacts?

Comment: Never heard of something similar, but it sounds kinda cool. I think nobody made it since changing the keyboard is nothing more than swiping across your `space` button (on my Android phone at least).

Comment: Yes however since I am sometimes using four different languages it becomes annoying. Especially because most of the time you don't think about it until you realize you've made some mistakes. And then back to correct.

Comment: I do understand that. Congratz on knowing so many languages tho :D I am not sure how would you even make this app. It should be aware of all the users you interact with within different chat apps (regular sms, whatsapp, facebook msnger, viber etc.) :D

Comment: @Victor: This question should have been closed a year ago, as it is not a programming question. Use https://android.stackexchange.com for non-programming Android questions.

Comment: So typical of SO. People complaining about the question not complying perfectly to the rules and people downvoting without leaving a comment. Usefulness of these attitudes is still to understand to me.

Comment: I don't have your answer but I was very interested in the "behind the scenes" of it, the code part. Because an Android Keyboard is an app just like any other. And both apps (the messenger and the keyboard) should communicate. This is of my interest. I don't expect opening a SO question to get app recommendations. This is why I'm downvoting.

Answer (score 2):

### No

And here is why: the User can set the keyboard in the settings for the phone. Also called input method editor (IME) by google.

As you can see in this developers guide, you can [create your own IME](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html).

**But the problem is, you need to get the Contact data from the App that you are running (What's App, Telegram, Slack, etc), and unless they support that, what I very much doubt, you will not pull this off.**

---

*Maybe, quite hackish.*

What might work is that the moment you open your custom IME, it takes a screenshot (not sure it could do that). Use that screenshot to parse out the Contact name. Try to match that with the Accounts on the phone. And use that to set the keyboard... But that is not a Keyboard I would like to have on my phone if it wasn't developed my me!